# foreach in foreach list c#

Tags: c#, foreach

The `GalleryDetail.Id` is `148` when it enters the first `foreach` loop, and the `GalleryDetail.Id` is `148` when it enters the second `foreach` loop. But it does not enter the first `foreach` loop again. It continues from the second. How do I get it to re-enter the first loop here?

NOTE: I do not have direct access from the `GalleryDetail.Id` request.

```
var detailList = await _repo.GalleryDetail.GetAllAsync();

foreach (var item in mapped.GalleryDetails)
{
    foreach (var item2 in detailList)
    {
        if (item.Id != item2.Id)
        {
            var mapped3 = _mapper.Map<GalleryDetails>(item2);
            await _repo.GalleryDetail.DeleteAsync(mapped3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is `mapped.GalleryDetails` in this context?

Comment: Now you have a nested loop. Do you want to consume them in parallel (one element from each collection)?

Comment: mapped.GalleryDetails => This is my GalleryDetail model list in the request I sent.

Comment: I want it to compare with the second foreach by entering the first foreach again. I have two lists. One is in the database and the other is in the request. If there is a missing data from the database in the request, I want it to be deleted from the database.

Comment: Agreed with @Korfu on more clarification. Also how big is the DeatilList? What version of EF? Perhaps take us through in English what you are trying to achieve.  As much as I love LINQ, my gut feel so far is I would stick with foreach like you have done, but really clarify what you are doing. It will make it much easier for you to come back to in the future (or other devs)

Comment: With the answer I approved, most of my problem was solved. Since I only use Ef Core, I wrote a new foreach method to delete in the form of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not necessary to use 2 loop here, you can use LinQ instead. And you should not leave async Delete inside foreach loop, because it will connect to you database mutiple time. Example:

```
var detailList = await _repo.GalleryDetail.GetAllAsync();
//Map the whole list
var detailListMapped = _mapper.Map<List<GalleryDetails>>(detailList);
//Use LinQ to find database items not in request
var deletedList = detailListMapped.Where(x => !mapped.GalleryDetails.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)).ToList();
//Entity Framework have RemoveRange function, you should use it here
await _repo.GalleryDetail.RemoveRangeAsync(deletedList );
```